Schemas validity error : Element 'rss': No matching global declaration available for the validation root
Here is the xml feed in question:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" 
  xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Kencove Farm Fence</title>
    <link>https://kencove.com/fence/</link>
    <description>Kencove fence product offerings.</description>
    <item>
      <g:id>A-7002500239</g:id>
      <title>
        <![CDATA[Z-Tags Marker - Black]]>
      </title>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[<p></p>]]>
      </description>
      <g:condition>NEW</g:condition>
      <g:image_link>[{'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/ken-odoo-prod-public/products/a-7002500239_2021-44275.jpg', 'slug': 'a-7002500239_2021-44275.jpg', 'alt_name': 'A-7002500239,main', 'extension': '.jpg', 'mimetype': 'image/jpeg'}]</g:image_link>
      <g:price>11.99</g:price>
      <g:weight>0.0550 pounds</g:weight>
      <g:brand>Kencove</g:brand>
      <g:mpn>A-7002500239</g:mpn>
    </item>

And here is the error I get when validating against googles schema for rss feeds:
Schemas validity error : Element 'rss': No matching global declaration available for the validation root
Here is the python script I have creating the feed for google:

    # Initialize the RSS feed structure
    rss = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
    rss += '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">'
    rss += '<channel>'
    rss += '<title>Kencove Farm Fence</title>'
    rss += '<link>https://kencove.com/fence/</link>'
    rss += '<description>Kencove fence product offerings.</description>'

    for item in results:
        # Escape XML characters in dynamic content
        # description = saxutils.escape(item.description or "")
        # name = saxutils.escape(item.name or "")

        rss += '<item>'
        rss += f'<g:id>{item.default_code}</g:id>'
        rss += f'<title><![CDATA[{item.name}]]></title>'
        rss += f'<description><![CDATA[{item.description}]]></description>'
        rss += '<g:condition>NEW</g:condition>'
        rss += f'<g:image_link>{item.image_data}</g:image_link>'

        # Price formatting
        if item.price and item.price > 0:
            rss += f'<g:price>{item.price:.2f}</g:price>'

        # Weight adjustment
        if item.weight:
            bumped_weight = item.weight * Decimal("1.1")  # Add 10% to weight
            rss += f'<g:weight>{bumped_weight} pounds</g:weight>'

        rss += '<g:brand>Kencove</g:brand>'
        rss += f'<g:mpn>{item.default_code}</g:mpn>'
        rss += '</item>'

    rss += '</channel>'
    rss += '</rss>'
    rss = rss.replace("&", "&amp;")

I tried adding the <rss version="2.0" in to solve the problem but it did not work.
Here is the validation schema from google:
http://www.gstatic.com/productsearch/static/reviews/5.0/merchant_reviews.xsd

You should use an API to generate XML content in python, not using string concatenation. That way you ensure that you generate a valid XML content.

Please provide fuller Python code including all import lines and output. We simply see your string concatenation of markup which should be avoided. See What's so bad about building XML with string concatenation?
